# Android get Data from edittext inside custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I am new in Android. I am filling data inside listview component and after that also do some editing and then fetch from the adapter edittext data. I am getting but its previous data not current edited data.

My Java code is as,

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Cursor c = db.getData();
                    List<ClientDetail> arrayList = new ArrayList<ClientDetail>();
                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        ClientDetail cd = new ClientDetail();
                        cd.setContactID(c.getString(1));
                        cd.setContactname(c.getString(2));
                        cd.setRefCompanyId_EntityMaster(c.getString(3));
                        arrayList.add(cd);
                    }
                    List<Worklog> wl = RSMIT.getInstance().getWorklogList();
                    List<Worklog> wolo = new ArrayList<Worklog>();
                    View v;
                    EditText et;
                    Worklog worklog = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
                        v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView);
                        et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtwldes);
                        chkwl = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkwl);
                        spinner = (NiceSpinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        spinner1 = (NiceSpinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                        worklog = new Worklog();
                        if (wl.get(i).getIsTaskEnable() == null) {
                            worklog.setIsTaskEnable(null);
                        } else {
                            worklog.setIsTaskEnable(wl.get(i).getIsTaskEnable());
                        }

                        if (wl.get(i).getTaskStatusId() == null) {
                            worklog.setTaskStatusId(null);
                        } else {
                            worklog.setTaskStatusId(wl.get(i).getTaskStatusId());
                        }

                        worklog.setIsWorkLogEnable(wl.get(i).getIsWorkLogEnable());
                        worklog.setColor(wl.get(i).getColor());
                        worklog.setIsCheckTickTicked(wl.get(i).getIsCheckTickTicked());
                        worklog.setTaskType(wl.get(i).getTaskType());
                        if (et.isEnabled() == true) {
                            worklog.setWorklogDescription(et.getText().toString().trim());
                        } else {
                            worklog.setWorklogDescription("");
                        }

                        Log.e("edt txt", et.getText().toString());
                        if (chkwl.isChecked()) {
                            worklog.setIsCopy("true");
                        } else {
                            worklog.setIsCopy("false");
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
                            if (spinner1.getItem(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Select")) {
                                worklog.setClientID(null);
                            } else {
                                worklog.setClientID(spinner1.getItem(0));
                            }
                        }

                        if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("09:00-09:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0900");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("09:30-10:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0930");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("10:00-10:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1000");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("10:30-11:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1030");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("11:00-11:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1100");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("11:30-12:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1130");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("12:00-12:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1200");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("12:30-13:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox1230");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("13:00-13:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0100");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("13:30-14:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0130");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("14:00-14:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0200");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("14:30-15:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0230");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("15:00-15:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0300");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("15:30-16:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0330");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("16:00-16:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0400");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("16:30-17:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0430");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("17:00-17:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0500");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("17:30-18:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0530");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("18:00-18:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0600");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("18:30-19:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0630");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("19:00-19:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0700");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("19:30-20:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0730");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("20:00-20:30")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0800");
                        } else if (wl.get(i).getTimeTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("20:30-21:00")) {
                            worklog.setTimeTrack("chkbox0830");
                        }
                        wolo.add(worklog);
                    }


                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(wolo,
                            new TypeToken<List<Worklog>>() {
                            }.getType());

                    Log.e("Element Value", element.getAsJsonArray().toString());
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        }
    });
```

So, My question is for how can i get edited values from inside listview edittext? Thank you.

Comment: Since you are new in Android, I will suggest you to better switch to recyclerview instead of ListView.

Comment: if i used it, is it possible to get value from edittext...

Comment: of course, it is a better way of using a `list`, because it force you to `recycle` your `objects` in order to consume less memory and have a better performance and user experience. Once you build your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder`, your `single_row_layout.xml` and you declare everything to make it works, in your `adapter class` there will be a method (`onBindViewHolder`) in which you will `getvalue` or `setvalue` of every `view` that you put on your `single_row_layout.xml`.

Comment: i used it before. but main thing is my issue. just getting my edited data from it... thats it. please help me to solve it...

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting anymore your idea. What do you want to achieve?
a) everytime a single character is writed/deleted you want to make something happens?
b) everytime you click somewhere you want to get the value of a specific edittext which is inside your listview?
c) or what else?

Comment: but not only specific... but all edittext values inside listview. and then bind it into arraylist.

Comment: Then this is a strange request, because edittext in listview or recyclerview is bad practice. Instead, you could have a ViewGroup and dynamically add edit texts to it as needed then access these in different ways. The idea of "bad practice" is that you have to implement textwatcher listener every time an edittext in the listview get created (scrolling up/down) which is horrible. But if this is what you want, then you have to add to each edittext a textwatcher listener.

Comment: @GopalAmreliya you would need to use a text watcher for each edit text inside your listview. Then get the value from the edit text and bind it into your arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

> You should use a TextWatcher and use methods for before text change after text change please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
>
> This is sample code just to guide you.But please read the documentation first.

```
//suppose this is your edit text 
EditText et;
//addTextChange listener
et.addTextChangedListener(editTextTextWatcher);

private TextWatcher editTextTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        //Write your code to handel text changes here
    }
};
```

Comment: @GopalAmreliya this is just a sample code read the documentation and implement it for your desired text view.It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EG:

ObjectEntity.class:

```
public class ObjectEntity {
String name;
EditText editText;

public ObjectEntity() {
}

public ObjectEntity(String name, EditText editText) {
    this.name = name;
    this.editText = editText;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public EditText getEditText() {
    return editText;
}

public void setEditText(EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;
}}
```

In Adapter:

```
 ArrayList<ObjectEntity>arrayList= new ArrayList<ObjectEntity>();
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent,
                    false);
        }
        EditText mEdt=(EditText )convertView.findViewById(R.id.mEdext);
        arrayList.get(position).setEditText(mEdt);

        return convertView;

    }
```

In code  Activity:

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                EditText editText = arrayList.get(i).getEditText();

                String edtContent = editText.getText().toString();
                //check vule here

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: this wa getting error...like, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: - arrayList.size()=?
-You need add data to arrayList .

Comment: Post full code Activity.class  and Adapter.class . please!

Comment: You sure arrayList.size()>0 ?

Comment: Yes, you can .   You can use "abstract class onclicklistener".